# Jmeter while sending request with comma is generating 400 Bad Request error

Tags: jmeter

400 Bad Request issue with [this URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?key=AIzaSyAhpDEvHFjzUs2zUT8rYGrGjGfX1zPZEWM&location=39.08470153808594%2C-94.5835037231445) using JMeter. It works if I open it in a browser, but in JMeter giving a `400 bad request`

I tried setting `Content-Type` with other values such as `application/json` or `text/plain`. None of them worked.

I even tried putting these 2 parameters separately as `name` and `value` with URL encoding selected that also did not work
[image]

New key value can be used is AIzaSyAhpDEvHFjzUs2zUT8rYGrGjGfX1zPZEWM

Attached is my test plan

Comment: Can you see the request sent? For example with the proxy like in point 3 of https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/05/04/debug-jmeter-script/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the settings from JMeter:

**HTTPS Sampler:**

[image]

View Results Tree:

**Request:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: But when we add header manager to the request it is not working. When script recorded it had added Header manager as shown in pic above.

Answer (score 0):

It was issue with colon in header name it was causing the issue

**:authority**  Removed colon and it started working